# Send email notification when someone logs case activity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

Our company wants to know when the case activity is 75% of the original estimated hours.

However, I think that might be a bit of a tough call.

So, can someone explain how to send an email notification from Microsoft Dynamics CRM when someone logs any kind of "case activity" against a case? I am happy to use .NET code if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a workflow against the 'case activity' entities, add a condition to the workflow to only send an email when the the 'case activity' is related to a case. E.g. regarding case contains data.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer a Plugin for this kind of thing because you can do a lot more within a Plugin's context.

This is what I would imagine:

Whenever an activity record is created/modified/deleted; if it is regarding a case, the plugin will execute:

1. Get all regarding activities for the case
2. Sum up the `Duration`
3. If the `Duration Total` is 75% of the Case Estimate then fire a
   workflow

The workflow will then be configured to send an email. By combining the plugin with a workflow, you allow the email to be configurable if the wording/recipients/from needs to change in the future.

I would probably also pass in the `75%` as a configuration setting to the plugin so that this is also semi-configurable (doesn't involve code - but you'd need to modify the plugin registration).

The plugin would need to cater for

- New Activities being added
- Existing Activities being edited (Duration and/or State changes)

At first I thought you would also need to handle Deletes, but that would drop the Duration below the 75% so you wouldn't need to send an email.